# Generate JavaScript documentation with Doxygen

Tags: javascript, documentation, doxygen

I use PHP and JavaScript in my project, which I entirely code with netbeans 7.0.1. I really like how netbeans includes and uses the JavaDoc commenting style, both for PHP and JS code.

Now, I want to generate the code documentation from PHP as well as JS code. I know there are several ways doing it, but my main aim is to have the documentation for both parts in *one* documentation.

To explain it further: So e.g., I could use Doxygen and process the PHP files and JsDoc to process the JS files. The result would be, that I now have two different docs in two different folders - a result which I don't like. As I mentioned, I want both in one documentation.

So, first I went the way via using the doxygen helper js2doxy.pl (http://jsunit.berlios.de/internal.html), but that wasn't flexible enough. It works well with "normal" defined functions, but not with anonymous js functions.

After a bit of trying a lot I thought why not alter the FILE_PATTERNS option of document to process .js files, as the JavaDoc style of the comments are nearly identical to the ones used with PHP. And well, the result looks promising, *but* some functions are missing in the doc.

Here are examples:

```
/**
 * Definitions for the languages.
 * @memberof Language
 */
Language.Definitions = (function()
{
...
}
```

This works very well, I can see the documentation. But:

```
**
 * Definitions for the languages
 * @memberof Language
 */
Language.Definitions = (function()
{
    var Translations = {};

    /**
     * Replaces strings.
     * @memberof Language
     * @param string translation Translation string 
     * @param array parameters (optional) List of parameters
     * 
     * @return string replaced string
     */
    function replaceStrings(translation, parameters)
    {
       ...
    }
```

In this example I see the docs for Language.Definitions but not for replaceStrings(). Do you have any idea, what I am doing wrong? The same construct is process by JsDoc very well.

Also (part of Language.Definitions) ...

```
... 
return {
        /**
         * Initialize translations
         * 
         * @memberof Language
         */
        initTranslations: function()
        {
           ...
        } 
... 
}
```

... is not shown in the documentation.

I also wouldn't mind if someone would show me how to best merge the two outputs of doxygen and JsDoc into one documentation.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Greetings!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See the special command [\fn](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdfn) to explicitly declare the function in the doxygen, preferably in the header of source, like this:

```
/*!
 * Language
 * Declare the root class
 * \Class Language
 */

/*! 
 * definitions is a property in the Language class
 * \property Definitions definitions
 */

/*!
 * Document the Definitions static class that used as property in the Language class
 * \Class Definitions
 */

/*!
 * Replaces strings
 * Document the static method for the Definitions class
 * \fn string replaceStrings(translation, parameters)
 * \memberof Definitions
 * \param string translation Translation string 
 * \param array parameters (optional) List of parameters
 * \return string replaced string
 */

Language.definitions = (function()
{
    var Translations = {};

    function replaceStrings(translation, parameters)
    {
       ...
    }
```

Comment: After that long time, I finally could test it and it seems to work. Two things I had to change: `\Class` must be `\class` (lower case) and `\property Definitions definitions` must be `\property Definitions Definitions`.
Unfortunately the class hierarchy is not considered. I tried things like `\property Language.Definitions Language.Definitions` and `\class Language.Definitions` which partly works, but there are still quirks left (e.g. doxygen compiler warnings).

Comment: check the doxygen pages, there is support for Javascript. Apart from that , works for me.

Comment: @Zane, doxygen javascript [pages](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/helpers.html#doxfilt_js) don't load could you please tell the steps to config it to support javascript?

Comment: @Wagner Pinheiro, Where the file located for make doxyden document js projects?

Comment: @user3933607, doxygen don't document js, you must use explicit [special commands](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/commands.html) to do that. Or, you can use a specific [script](https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/helpers.html) to parse the javascript.

Comment: @WagnerPinheiro, Thanks, so what is this [about](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/helpers.html#doxfilt_js) as its links don't load for me? and how can I document javascript using special commands or the script?

Comment: @user3933607, neither for me, i found out the script [here](https://github.com/mrdon/jsunit/blob/master/jsunit/util/js2doxy.pl).

Comment: @WagnerPinheiro, where should I put the script? (My platform is windows).

Comment: @WagnerPinheiro, could you please help me to fix it out?

Comment: @user3933607, see: [How to run Perl script on a windows machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13160223/how-to-run-perl-script-on-a-windows-machine)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87929/discussion-between-user3933607-and-wagner-pinheiro).

Comment: @user3933607: here is something that helped me: http://coherent-labs.com/blog/documenting-javascript-with-doxygen/ You need doxygen.js - the page tells you where to find it and how to configure doxygen to make it work

Comment: @Zane, I am new to doxygen and I use its UI for documentation, I put doxygen.js and Doxyfile to its bin directory, how can I config it?