# How to run Perl script on a windows machine?

Tags: perl

What is the free solution to this problem?

Comment: My vote is for `Strawberry Perl`.

Comment: did you even do a tiny search?

Answer (score 4):

There is [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) or [ActiveState ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl) (there is a free community edition of ActivePerl).

Answer (score 3):

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) (more than just perl, but you get to use perl in an environment more closely resembling its native one)