# Auto generating documentation for uncommented JavaScript

Tags: javascript, doxygen

I have been given a JavaScript project to maintain. If it were C or C++ then I would run it through Doxygen and get some decent docs, even if there were no Doxygen comments in the code. This helps give me an overview for the project, before I dive in to serious code exploring.

I can't get Doxygen to generate anything for JS and the links on the [official web page](http://www.doxygen.nl/helpers.html#doxfilt_js) are broken.

How to get Doxygen to work with (uncommented) JS code?

Comment: I see. Is there any way that I can rephrase the question which would be acceptable?

Comment: as far as I can tell, updated question doesn't look for software recommendations anymore (nice edit!). Per my reading of [this meta guidance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773) it may probably be better fit for Stack Overflow than Programmers, but I wouldn't bet on that

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will continue to Google & post any positive findings in order to help others.

Comment: Ha ha ha ... sigh! Only **after** I edited the question to remove any trace of asking for a software recommendation was it put on hold for ... asking for a software recommendation  (in fact it was put on hold **after** I had accepted an answer).

Comment: don't worry (yet) - there are 2 reopen votes on it and I flagged for moderator to take a look

Comment: @gnat, I truly appreciate your help. It's guys like you who give me faith in the SE community.

Comment: @mawg doxygen is the name of the product / program all in lower case and should, in my opinion, be in lower case (I've seen others "correcting" it as well, good luck "correcting" everything).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shame about the broken links. I found [this](http://keepoint.com/static/js/jsunit/docs/internal.html) that will help you, and a [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320464/generate-javascript-documentation-with-doxygen) question about it.

The js2dox perl script basically converts your js code (with the comments) to pseudo-C++ code that is correctly formatted for doxygen to work on. You will have to add some special comment tags to your js to correctly include parameters, return codes and types. These are special tags \tparam, \treturn and \type - they're not valid doxygen tags but will be turned into the correct parts of the C++ code.

The js2dox.pl script can be found in the jsunit build. I'm not sure why it isn't part of the doxygen site!

Comment: "js2doxy - utility to convert JavaScript into something Doxygen can understand" from your first link is perfect!